# What is the 1st derivative i.r.t. coordinates for a vector function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

For a vector function $f(x,y,z)$, we have the divergence
$$\nabla \cdot f(x,y,z) = \frac{\partial{f}_{x}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial{f}_{y}}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial{f}_{z}}{\partial z}$$
, the gradient (or Jacobian)
$$\nabla f(x,y,z) = \left( \begin{matrix}
        \frac{\partial{f}_{x}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial{f}_{x}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial{f}_{x}}{\partial z} \\
        \frac{\partial{f}_{y}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial{f}_{y}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial{f}_{y}}{\partial z} \\
        \frac{\partial{f}_{z}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial{f}_{z}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial{f}_{z}}{\partial z} \\
        \end{matrix} \right)$$
and the vector Laplacian
$$\Delta f(x,y,z) = \left( \frac{\partial^2{f}_{x}}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2{f}_{x}}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2{f}_{x}}{\partial z^2} , \frac{\partial^2{f}_{y}}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2{f}_{y}}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2{f}_{y}}{\partial z^2} , \frac{\partial^2{f}_{z}}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2{f}_{z}}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2{f}_{z}}{\partial z^2} \right)$$
where ${f}_{x},{f}_{y},{f}_{z}$ are the $x,y,z$ components of the vector function $f$ respectively.

My question is, is there a symbol/operator specifically for this expression:
$$\left( \frac{\partial{f}_{x}}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial{f}_{y}}{\partial y} , \frac{\partial{f}_{z}}{\partial z} \right)$$
, where each component is differentiated in respect to its direction? I'm not sure if this operator would be useful at all, or have any applications, but my intuition tells me such operator should exist, for some reason.

Comment: just to say for the laplace, all of the second derivatives should be summed in each entry. (consider when f is  a 1D vector of three variables)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient .Look under differential derivative. It looks closely related to your inquiry.

Comment: @Rod: But that article is talking about scalar functions, which does not apply to vector functions. And most importantly, it's really just the gradient.

Comment: I don't think there is any specific symbol for that. But from personal experience it does have an application in numerical methods - we use it as a preconditioner in our iterative solver.